# Spring cloud stream if error occur, moved to a reject topic (rabbitmq)

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

What happen if any exception is occurred during consume the jms request, is cloud stream handle the exception ( will error move to any specific topic or queue, same scenario for during publish a message) ?

```
  @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
        public void handle(Request req) throw Exception {
            // logic
           throw new Exception()
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried reading the docs? [Spring Cloud Stream Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/)

You will be surprised what a little bit of reading can do for you

Comment: ohh got it, Thank you Vinicius Carvalho!